# Unable to make GeoPackages and MBTiles compatible in MapTiler Cloud using gdal_translate

Tags: gdal-translate, geopackage, mbtiles, tile-server, maptiler

I'm using gdal_translate to convert TIF files to GeoPackage and MBTiles. The geopackage/MBTiles are uploaded to MapTiler Cloud. They upload to MapTiler Cloud even if they are not "clean tileset" from MapTiler Desktop.

[image]

However, there are errors with the zoom levels

- Geopackage 0 to 5
- MBTiles 20 to 20

These are the script I used

TIF to GeoPackage

```
gdal_translate -of GPKG -oo ZOOM_LEVEL=13 input_3857.tif output.gpkg
```

TIF to MBTiles

```
gdal_translate -of MBTiles -oo ZOOM_LEVEL=13 input_3857.tif output.mbtiles
```

Is there a way to convert a TIF to a GeoPackage/MBTiles that is 100% compatible in MapTiler Cloud just like if it was converted via MapTiler Desktop?

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Are your MBTiles and GeoPackage OK with QGIS?

Comment: No errors, the gpkg/mbtiles are uploaded succesfully but they are problematic due to the zoom level. Yes, both show up in QGIS.

Comment: Could you make a clear comparison about how the problematic things are in the GDAL  and MapTiler versions?

Comment: The gpkg/mbtiles made via gdal_translate have problematic zoom errors when uploaded to MapTiler Cloud. The former has 0-5, the later 20-20 so they're useless. The gpkg made via MapTiler Desktop has correct zoom levels and usable when uploaded to MapTiler Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be 100% sure of the compatibility, use MapTiler Desktop.
The other solutions might vary in output and MapTiler is not able to guarantee that their internal settings will comply with MapTiler Cloud requirements at all times.
If you are a MapTiler Cloud customer, please reach out to me at support@maptiler.com with further details and we can discuss what solution would be the best for you.

Jiri
MapTiler Support